# git merge --no-ff myfeature on Windows

Tags: git

Is it a normal behavior that when merging a **feature** branch with **--no-ff** option on a **master** branch to still have all the commits from the feature branch incorporated on a dev branch ? Is it not supposed to have just a merge commit on a dev branch ? When I run:

```
git log --graph
```

I see see only a merge commit on the dev branch.
But when I run

```
git log
```

I see all the feature branch commits as well and the last one as a merge commit:

**Logs on a feature branch feature-2:**

```
$ git log --oneline -4
cd98c0f Add f6
c1cd3e9 Add f5
33f5382 Add f4
4ca2889 Remove to_do file
```

**Logs on a master branch after merge:**

```
$ git log --oneline -6
35ef8a9 Merge branch 'feature-2'
549b1eb Add title for the features
cd98c0f Add f6
c1cd3e9 Add f5
33f5382 Add f4
4ca2889 Remove to_do file
```

On the other hand, the graph is correct (on **master** branch):

```
$ git log --graph
*   commit 35ef8a939fb6cffb763b030f540f9256144f6979
|\  Merge: 549b1eb cd98c0f
| | Author: xxxxxx
| | Date:   Mon May 2 17:11:42 2016 +0200
| |
| |     Merge branch 'feature-2'
| |
| * commit cd98c0f5a83cc8f5cd57c48ac56ba83cc1b49886
| | Author: xxxxxxxxxx
| | Date:   Mon May 2 17:09:23 2016 +0200
| |
| |     Add f6
| |
| * commit c1cd3e94906e13c15ee22dfadcca55961e76ac20
| | Author: xxxxxxxxxx
| | Date:   Mon May 2 17:09:14 2016 +0200
| |
| |     Add f5
| |
| * commit 33f538230ddee39eb0eb2cec7528e17e744a4479
| | Author: xxxxxxxxxx
| | Date:   Mon May 2 17:09:04 2016 +0200
| |
| |     Add f4
| |
| * commit 4ca2889de92cb7cb326783a6905554f6cfe932ca
| | Author: xxxxxxxxxx
| | Date:   Mon May 2 17:08:35 2016 +0200
| |
| |     Remove to_do file
| |
* | commit 549b1eb6f4715d7abfae6a7677524ee448300493
|/  Author: xxxxxxxxxx
|   Date:   Mon May 2 17:10:23 2016 +0200
|
|       Add title for the features
|
*   commit 0b52bd7ca2a6e02aeefd84c0f80a1f69d3f547b7
```

So what's the problem here ?Is it just Windows ?

OS: Windows 7 x64
Git version:  2.8.1.windows.1

Thank you

Comment: Use `--first-parent` if you do not want commits from merged branch to be shown.

Comment: @PetSerAl: thanks a lot, I didn't know that option and was really confused to see all the branch commits on master branch.